# testing asynchronous callbacks with Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a class A and an interface B. A calls B to update A's property someProperty.

```
interface B
{
    IAsyncResult BeginSetProperty(string str, AsyncCallback callback); 
    bool EndSetProperty(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

A calls B with `b.BeginSetProperty(str, someCallback)` where `someCallback` calls `SomeProperty = b.EndSetProperty(result)`.

How do I stub B so that someProperty will be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2009/04/).